# What happened to the Minecraft Update feed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the launcher, prior to version 1.8, Minecraft used to have a log of the updates that were implemented in each version. For example:

> Minecraft Version x
>
> - Bug fixes
> - Added features
> - Removed Herobrine

But now, the only thing I have seen since Microsoft bought Minecraft is a promotional cape notice. And since then rabbits, Sponges, new enchantments and new enchantment features have been added, and even a new boss, but no mention of it in the launcher?

Does anyone know if there is something I'm missing, or if it's to do with Microsoft's take over?

What I'm looking for is a list of all the new features that have been added in each update. The [Minecraft Update Tumblr](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/) only shows what shows in the launcher, which is not what I'm looking for. Eg, the latest update news in that is

> We have released Minecraft version 1.8.4 to fix some security issues. Updating is highly recommended from older versions, and is 100% compatible with all 1.8 versions.

*This tells me nothing about anything that was added to the game*.

So to clarify, my question is this: **Where can I find a detailed list of all the new fixes/new features/"Removed Herobrine" logs for each update?** (If there even is one)

Comment: `Note: Not asking why the dev's decided to stop it, just why it has stopped.` That seems like the same thing to me. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Chipperyman I think it's a more broad way of asking the question. If it is a dev's decision, then that's the answer to the question I'm asking. If there is another reason, whatever that may be, that could also be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update notes you are looking for are not usually present on the [tumblr](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/), as you noted. There are two places, however, where you can find the information you seek.

#### Official Mojang blog

They can, however be found in the [official Mojang blog](https://mojang.com/) on their main site. The older posts can be hard to find though, but should be able to find them with some googling, I suggest searching for

```
site:mojang.com -site:bugs.mojang.com minecraft [version]
```

to limit the results to actual results. Note that these posts are often updated, even changing the title in some cases, such as the one for [1.8.2](https://mojang.com/2015/02/minecraft-1-8-2-is-now-available/).

Sadly, the information about bugfixes is often scattered among [multiple](https://mojang.com/2014/12/minecraft-1-8-2-pre1-christmas-gift-edition/) [posts](https://mojang.com/2015/02/minecraft-1-8-2-pre7-almost-there-just-one-more/) for pre-releases as well as the main post, making them hard to follow. They also seem to be incomplete.

#### The wiki's version history

A much more convenient way of browsing the changes is offered by the wiki, in the [Version History](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history) article, neatly sorted by major and minor version. There is an extra page for [development versions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history/Development_versions) as well, if you want to check out the snapshots or pre-releases.

The downside is that this information is user-curated and takes some time to be gathered, especially for non-obvious changes, such as the [blacklisting of player head textures not hosted on a mojang server](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/32xdcl/the_end_of_custom_player_heads/) in 1.8.4.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is the [Minecraft Update tumblr](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/), which does include minecraft changelogs, but with the recent other posts (International hello, and Scrolls promo) the changelogs have been pushed to the bottom of the view, just scroll down.

Answer (score 1):

**September 2023:** The Minecraft Wiki has migrated from Fandom to an independent wiki host, and the high-quality information from the Gamepedia days is still there! The [Java Edition version history](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_version_history) section has comprehensive community-maintained changelogs which I'd recommend as your main source.

---

As mentioned by MrLemon, the minecraft.net blog posts are the successor to changelogs on Tumblr. If you're interested in a full list of bugs that were fixed in a specific development cycle, then you can use a JQL query in Minecraft's bugtracker. For example, to find bugs fixed during the development of 1.19 you could use [`fixVersion > 1.18.2 AND fixVersion <= 1.19`](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-100923?jql=fixVersion%20%3E%201.18.2%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3C%3D%201.19).

If you prefer videos to text, [Slicedlime's YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@slicedlime) has very high-quality and thorough update videos. He also makes accompaniment videos that detail the technical changes in each version.

Speaking of technical changes, another useful resource is [Misode's Technical Changelog](https://misode.github.io/changelog), which allows you to filter changes based on what parts of the game they affect, such as NBT, assets, or commands.

All of these sources are also available for snapshots, so you can keep track of changes as Mojang works on each update.